# Problem with Python 3 and Pythontex

Tags: pythontex

I've install portable WinPython (`python-3.6.0b4.amd64` from http://winpython.github.io/). 
I use `Miktex` and `TexStudio` as IDE.
I'm compiling the example(pythontex_gallery.tex) of the `pythonTeX` package, It doesn't work for me in `Win10`. Path to python is in `path` variable

When I try to run pythontex fromwithin `TexStudio` (`pythontex.exe --interpreter "python:py -3" %.tex`) or via command line after tex-file compiling I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "d:\Programs\LaTeX\MikTex\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.py", line 55, in <module> import pythontex3 as pythontex ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythontex3'
```

but `pythontex3.py` in the same folder as `pythontex.py`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should set your PYTHONPATH environment variable.
I don't know Winpython, but the documentation (https://github.com/winpython/winpython/wiki/Environment)
suggests you can do this by editing the file settings\winpython.ini in your winpython install dir.
You should modify it so it contains a line like
PYTHONPATH = D:\Programs\LaTeX\MikTex\scripts\pythontex

I did not try it, but it should work this way!

Comment: Unfortunantly, it does not help me. I have added PYTHONPATH as you mention, but error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is the problem was. I used `python-3.6.0b4.amd64` which is probably unstable. With `WinPython's` `python-3.4.4.amd64` it even  do not need in PYTHONPATH declaration, only system PATH variable one need to be set the path to the python distribution.